# event.getObject() in row editing for primefaces sends the old value to the bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to use the feature of prime faces which allows user to edit the row data in the table itself.I have followed this link to achieve it:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowEditing.jsf

When I say edit user the new values which are entered are not sent to the bean.It still shows the old values only.

My code in JSF:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{mybean.userList}"
        var="item"
        id="dataTab"
        widgetVar="usersTable"
        tableStyleClass="data"  paginator="true" rows="5"  
        filteredValue="#{userController.filteredUsers}"
        editable="true"
        rowKey="#{item}">

    <p:ajax event="rowEdit"   listener="#{mybean.onEdit}" update=":userForm:growl" />  
    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{mybean.onCancel}" update=":userForm:growl" /> 
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:outputPanel>  
            <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />  
            <p:inputText id="globalFilter"     onkeyup="('usersTable').filter()"   style="width:150px" />  
        </p:outputPanel>     
    </f:facet>


    <p:column sortBy="#{item.firstName}" filterBy="#{item.firstName}" 
        filterMatchMode="startsWith">
        <p:cellEditor> 
            <f:facet name="header">  
                <h:outputText value="First Name" />  
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText  value="#{item.firstName}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">  
                <p:inputText value="#{item.firstName}" style="width:100%"/>  
            </f:facet>  
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column  sortBy="#{item.lastName}" filterBy="#{item.lastName}" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
        <p:cellEditor> 
            <f:facet name="header">  
                <h:outputText value="Last Name" />  
            </f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="Update" style="width:6%">  
                <p:rowEditor />  
            </p:column>    


</p:dataTable>
```

My code in bean:

```
public String onEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
    User user=(User)event.getObject());
    user.getFirstName();
}
```

code in the bean for getting the list in ui:

```
 public List<UserBean> getUsersList(){
        List<UserBean> retval = new ArrayList<>();            
        for (Object[] tuple : myFacade.getUserList()) {
            UserBean ub = new UserBean();
            ub.setFirstName((String) tuple[0]);
            ub.setLastName((String)tuple[1]);
            ub.setEmailAddress((String)tuple[2]);
            ub.setOfficeNumber((String)tuple[3]);
            ub.setRole((String)tuple[4]);                
            retval.add(ub);
        }
        return retval;
    }
```

I have tried the suggestions that were given in some of the posts but they did not work.Could anyone let me know how can I get the new values.I am using glassfish 4.0,primefaces 3.5.

Comment: Among other possible problems, your code doesn't properly close the JSF tags. Was this a copy and paste problem?

Comment: sounds like conversion/validation failed. Can you add a message component to your form to verify that?

Comment: @patstuart yes it is just a copy paste error and is fine in my jsf page.

Comment: @kolossus I added the message component p:growl and it does not show me any validation/conversion error.I am just changing the first name from "abc" to "abcd".

Comment: @Avi I agree this sounds like a conversion/validation problem. Could you please post all code dealing with userList?

Comment: i added the code which gets the list...the facade calls the getUserList method which is call to the database and return a list of objects which I am displaying there. Could you let me know if that is causing the problem.

Comment: @patstuart ay suggestions about that..I have added the code in my question itself.Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, it's almost impossible to figure out because the code you posted has all sorts of problems. You are performing a complex operation in a getter, which you should _never_ do (PrimeFaces will throw all sorts of fit). You are ignoring generics altogether, so it's impossible to tell what's being passed. You posted the code for user*s*List, not userList, and it's returning what appears to be a list of UserBean, not User. Try fixing some of these fundamental problems with your code, and maybe you'll find the bug while you're fixing it.

Comment: @patstuart  that was a typo error my list that I mention in the data table and in the backing bean are same. I just checked that again.Also what am I doing is I am getting all the users from DB and then storing these values in a new class called UserBean and my table displays a list of UserBeans only. I tried the functionality of delete where one of my columns has a button on click of that a dialog is opened and the values are shown correctly. I tried the same for Edit and it worked. But for edit if I use this functionality it does not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to figure out the problem..Every time when I am getting the list in the getter method I am calling the database to load the data..But this should be done only if the list is null.The following code gives you a clear picture:

```
public List<UserBean> getUsersList(){


        if(retval == null)
        {
            retval = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Object[] tuple : myFacade.getUserList()) {
            UserBean ub = new UserBean();
            ub.setFirstName((String) tuple[0]);
            ub.setLastName((String)tuple[1]);
            ub.setEmailAddress((String)tuple[2]);
            ub.setOfficeNumber((String)tuple[3]);
            ub.setRole((String)tuple[4]);

            retval.add(ub);
        }
        }
        return retval;
    }
```

So getUsersList is my value of var in the p:datatable and now when I call the onEdit it will check for the list if it is null it does a database call or does not call the database.

Comment: I had the same problem, and this is right answer. Thanks!

Comment: Doing bussiness logic in getters is not advisable. Instead, use some method to initialize your bean, like `f:viewAction`.