# PrimeFaces 5.1 + editable dataTable + fileUpload column

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, datatable

I am using an editable `<p:dataTable>` where each `<p:column>` contains a `<p:cellEditor>`. I use one particular `<p:column>` to represent a property (let's call it *chemin*) of the model item used to store the name of a file (uploaded by the user). The corresponding `<p:cellEditor>` is as follows:

- in `<f:facet>` contains a `<p:fileUpload>` and an `<h:outputLink>`
- out `<f:facet>` contains a `<h:outputLink>`

I wanted to implement the following: when the user clicks the `<p:rowEditor>` (pencil icon), (1) the `<p:fileUpload>` is displayed, (2) the user then selects and uploads a file and (3) when the user validates the update (by clicking the check mark) the column displays a link to the freshly uploaded file, this means the current model item is updated accordingly: the *chemin* property will contain the name of the freshly uploaded file.

The code below implements correctly steps (1) to (2), but step (3) is not working.

**Version.xhtml**

```
<h:form id="RUDForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:dataTable
        id="versionDT"
        var="version"
        value="#{versionController.rechercherToutVersion()}"
        editable="true"
        paginator="true"
        rows="3"
        dir="rtl"
        style="width: 100%"
        emptyMessage="#{messages.listeVide}">

        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{versionController.updateVersion(version)}" update=":RUDForm:versionDT" />

        ...

        <p:column headerText="#{messages.chemin}">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputLink
                        id = "versionCheminLink"
                        value="#{versionController.relativeUploadUrl(version.chemin)}"
                        target="_blank"
                        rendered = "#{version.chemin != null}"
                    >
                        <h:outputText styleClass="title-text" value="#{version.chemin}"/>

                    </h:outputLink>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:panelGrid
                        id="uploadUpdatePG"
                        dir="rtl"
                    >
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:fileUpload
                                    id = "versionChemin"
                                    fileUploadListener="#{versionController.fileUploadListenerUpdate}"
                                    mode="advanced"
                                    dragDropSupport="false"
                                    update=":RUDForm:versionDT:uploadUpdatePG"
                                    fileLimit="1"
                                    label="#{messages.unChoix}"
                                    uploadLabel="#{messages.upload}"
                                    cancelLabel="#{messages.annuler}"
                                    invalidSizeMessage = "#{messages.invalidSizeMessage}"
                                    invalidFileMessage = "#{messages.invalidFileMessage}"
                                    sizeLimit="1000000"
                                >
                                    <f:attribute name="version" value="#{version}" />
                                </p:fileUpload>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column>
                                <h:outputLink
                                    id = "versionCheminLinkReminder"
                                    value="#{versionController.relativeUploadUrl(version.chemin)}"
                                    target="_blank"
                                    rendered = "#{version.chemin != null}"
                                >
                                    <h:outputText styleClass="title-text" value="#{version.chemin}"/>

                                </h:outputLink>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
            <p:message for="versionChemin"/>
        </p:column>

        ...

        <p:column style="width:6%">
            <p:rowEditor />
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

**VersionController.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class VersionController extends GenericPageController implements Serializable
{

    ...

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{versionServiceImpl}")
    private VersionService versionService;
    public VersionService getVersionService() {
        return versionService;
    }
    public void setVersionService(VersionService versionService) {
        this.versionService = versionService;
    }

    private UploadedFile file;
    public UploadedFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }
    public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    ...

    public void updateVersion(Version version)
    {
        if (getVersionService().updateVersion(version))
        {
            addInfoByKey("msgUpdateOk");
        }
        else
        {
            addErrorByKey("msgUpdateKo");
        }
    }

    ...

    public void fileUploadListenerUpdate(FileUploadEvent event)
    {
        setFile(event.getFile());
        uploadVersionUpdate((Version)event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("version"));
    }

    public void uploadVersionUpdate(Version version)
    {
        if ((getFile() != null) && (getFile().getSize() != 0))
        {
            version.setChemin(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS").format(new Date()) + addZeros(new Random().nextInt(10),3) + getFile().getFileName());
            upload(getFile(),version.getChemin());
            addInfoByKey("RUDForm:uploadUpdatePG","uploadOk");
        }
        else
        {
            addErrorByKey("RUDForm:uploadUpdatePG","uploadKo");
        }
    }
}
```

My idea was to pass the model item being edited to the controller using a `<f:attribute>` in the `<p:fileUpload>`.

After upload success (in method *uploadVersionUpdate*, called by the `fileUploadListener`) the property *chemin* of the model item is updated with the name of the file actually uploaded.

I was hoping that when the user clicks the check mark (to validate the update), the line will display the new value of *chemin*.
This was not the case with the code above.

It looks like the `<p:rowEditor>` ignores the changes made by the `fileUploadListener`. Is there a way to force row edition take into account changes made by the *fileUploadListener* ?

PS: File Upload works fine (configuration is good) and row edition also works fine except for the *chemin* property.

**Screeshots:**

**Before Edition:**
[image: Before Edition]
Note the old *chemin* value: blabla**13**blabla.pdf

**After Clicking Edition (pencil) Icon and Selecting a new file to Upload:**
[image: After Clicking Edition (pencil) Icon and Selecting a new file to Upload]

**After Successfully Uploading a new File:**
[image: After Successfully Uploading a new File]
Note that the *chemin* property has been updated: blabla**12**blabla.pdf.

**After validating Edition: Clicking the Check Mark Icon:**
[image: After validating Edition: Clicking the Check Mark Icon]
Note that the *chemin* property displays old value: blabla**13**blabla.pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solution Found Here !](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143401/event-getobject-in-row-editing-for-primefaces-sends-the-old-value-to-the-bean)

The method populating the **dataTable** values was calling a service (which in turn was calling a repository querying the database) each time. 
The solution was to go to the database only when the list feeding the **dataTable** was null, thus transforming the following:

```java
public List<Version> rechercherToutVersion()
{
  return(getVersionService().rechercherToutVersion());
}
```

into:

```java
private List<Version> allVersions;

public List<Version> getAllVersions() {
  return allVersions;
}

public void setAllVersions(List<Version> allVersions) {
  this.allVersions = allVersions;
}

...

public List<Version> rechercherToutVersion()
{
  if (getAllVersions() == null)
  {
    setAllVersions(getVersionService().rechercherToutVersion());
  }
  return(getAllVersions());
}
```

That solved my problem, but even if the solution is more efficient from the point of view of database access, i had to modify my **saveVersion** and **deleteVersion** methods. Indeed, because the rows are not each time got from the database, when i delete a row in the **dataTable**, the deleted row is still displaying and if i add a new item, the item is not showing in the **dataTable**: i have to refresh the page to see modifications take place.

The solution to this new issue was either to "manually" remove or add an item from *allVersions* property or simply to reset it to null each time a *delete* or *save* is done. Example for delete :

```java
public void deleteVersion(Version version)
{
  if (getVersionService().deleteVersion(version))
  {
    setAllVersions(null);
    addInfoByKey("msgDeleteOk");
  }
  else
  {
    addErrorByKey("msgDeleteKo");
  }
}
```

Finally what frustrated me the most is the following: why in the original code version, update was working perfectly for other properties, but specifically not with the property bound to the file upload ?